# Laravel 5.1 - hasMany relation on multiple fields inside one table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get proper date returned for a hasMany relation. The difference between 'normal' hasMany relationships is that I'm trying to use 1 table which can be used by multiple models.

I have a setup as such (with a few more fields, but not important for example)

news:

- id
- title
- body

project:

- id
- title
- body

media:

- id
- file
- type (enum project / news)
- type_id

I do get results with the following in my models:

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Media','type_id');
}
```

And getting the results with the:

```
->with('media')
```

But when I have a news item with the same id as a project this will return the wrong data back. Is there a way, in eloquent, to also set the type=project||news in both Project and News model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a polymorphic relationship.
It will manage a `type` and `id` field for you and base the queries on them.

[Eloquent Relationships - Polymorphic](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Thanks! It's what I needed.